# window.open() returns null in IE11 if opening

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

In IE on Windows 10 with default settings, if I perform a `window.open()` against an external internet site from a page on my local machine or a server on my local network, I get `null`.

See my repro below. This doesn't happen in IE on Windows 7 or Google Chrome.

Interestingly, if I turn on "Enable Protected Mode" for the Intranet Zone (so that Protected Mode are the same in the Intranet Zone and Internet Zone), then the problem goes away. However, I need this to work without requiring users to do this.

I haven't found any clear Microsoft documentation that explains this behavior. I raised [an issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13026028/) on this on the EdgeHTML issues site, but wanted to see if the community on SO has any insight into why this is happening.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script>
        var popupWindow = null;

        function openWindow() {
            popupWindow = window.open('http://microsoft.com', '_blank', 'left=100;top=100;height=100;width=100');
        }

        function checkWindowStatus() {
            if (popupWindow) {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += '- Truthy reference. Closed? ' + popupWindow.closed + '</br>';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += '- Falsy reference: ' + popupWindow + '</br>';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Popup Issue</h2>
    <button onclick="openWindow()">Open Window</button>
    <button onclick="checkWindowStatus()">Check Window Status</button>
    <button onclick="popupWindow.close()">Close Window</button>
    <p id="status"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that protected mode doesn't allow to open new window outside of the current domain, so you can try to open the window with a blank page and after update the location.

```
<script>
    var popupWindow = null;

    function openWindow() {
        popupWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'left=100;top=100;height=100;width=100');
        popupWindow.location = 'http://microsoft.com';
    }

    function checkWindowStatus() {
        if (popupWindow) {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += '- Truthy reference. Closed? ' + popupWindow.closed + '</br>';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += '- Falsy reference: ' + popupWindow + '</br>';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this. However, after the window redirects to the new URL, its `closed` property is `true` and invoking `close()` on it does not close it.

Comment: @AndyGeek, I have the same situation... Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @DanielEduardoDelgadoDiaz Did you find a workaround?