# My add-in works in my W10/O16 environment but fails when MS tests using W10/O16. Why?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Our Add-in for MS Word failed validation again. They cited that it didn’t work in the Word 2016 Client on Windows 10. But I developed and tested it in W10/O16 and it works for me. I've had several other people test using W10/O16 and it works for them.  What could be so different about MS's testing setup?

They informed me they are testing using Azure VM's and provided a snapshot of the console errors they are seeing

```
POST https://word-edit-officeapps.live.com/we/RemoteUls.ashx?build=16.0.12231.32656&waccluster=IE3 500 MicrosoftAjax.js: 5
```

I've never seen this error before. They also showed another error I've never seen in any of my tests...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> 
starting at object with constructor 'a' | Property 
'bindings'  -> object with constructor 'OSF.DDA.BindingFacade'
--- property 'document' closes the cricle 
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Home.js:229)
at blah blah blah
at blah blah blah
at office.js:41
```

I look at line 229 in Home.js and it's

```
228:    Office.onReady(function (info) {
229:        log("Office.onReady info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
230:        isJqready(); // run other functions
231:    });
232:
233:    Office.initialize = function () {}; // empty initialize function
```

I was wondering if it is possible that their environment doesn't support ES6? I've coded Home.js in vanilla JavaScript ES6, not TypeScript.

As a test, I've converted my ES6 code to ES5. But I'm hesitant to resubmit not knowing exactly why it failed.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: I had a similar issue that I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808294/how-to-diagnose-failed-validation-of-word-add-in-when-it-works-on-my-own-setup).  I believe the add-in used Edge on my computer but used IE11 on the validation team's VM.  I suspect you'll be ok after converting to ES5.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually working on something similar. I can tell you the POST error is happening on OfficeOnline, not the desktop client so apparently they misreported that. Try running it on Office Online in various browsers.

It definitely needs to be either transpiled to ES5 or written natively in it because earlier versions of Word 2016 (before ~May this year) and in fact Word 2013 in general will need to run it in IE11 which does not support ES6.