# Why I can't set global variable to child window in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, childwindow

I am trying to do new functionality.
I was able to achieve what I want in modern browsers but not in the IE11.

```
  if (!window.IS_PRESENTING) {
      childWindow = window.open(window.location.pathname);
      childWindow.IS_PRESENTING = true;
      setupMainWindow();
    } else {
      setupChildWindow();
    }
```

In modern browsers **IS_PRESENTING** is being set on the child windows. But in the IE11 it doesnt work and the browser keeps opening new windows...

How can I fix this? Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be related, if not the same root cause: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45448779/2557263

Comment: Tried to disable the protected mode but gives same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue in IE 11. As a workaround, in IE 11, you can get the value of `window.IS_PRESENTING` in the opening window and set the opening window's `IS_PRESENTING` value according to it :

In the opening window:

```
targetWindow = window.opener;
var IS_PRESENTING = !targetWindow.IS_PRESENTING;  //targetWindow.IS_PRESENTING can get the value of window.IS_PRESENTING in child window
alert("The value of IS_PRESENTING is " + IS_PRESENTING);
```

Reference link: [Window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

Comment: Thanks, actually I came up with other solution. When creating window I have set the name for a window. Then I can check if the window name is equal to:
if (window.name !== nameForOpenedWindow) {
      openedWindow = window.open(window.location.pathname, nameForOpenedWindow);

Then I can check if this is the window I need by checking the name of the actual window.